# Can the search engines be modified to recognize Thor?

Tags: bug

When I search for [[norse] thor](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/search?q=[norse]+thor) I get one listing for Thor and 7 more with 'The'.  Searching for just [Thor](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/search?q=Thor) gets me 133 results and we currently only have 70 questions.

[image]

Comment: I wonder if this is site-specific. I usually use Google with _site:mythology.stackexchange.com_ to search on SE. Of course, for Mythology it doesn't work yet because it is private...

Comment: The obvious workaround is to enquote the word "thor": http://mythology.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bnorse%5D+%22thor%22. This probably isn't really a fixable thing, in that it probably stems from overzealous fuzzy matching, which I imagine is difficult to tune.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Searching using "Thor" works fairly well. For Thor at least no modification seems necessary.

[image]